# Why do we need another term for this solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the differential equation $$y''-6y'+9y = 0   $$

Using a auxiliary equations we find that $Ae^{3x}$ is a solution.

The auxiliary equation has repeated roots of $3$.

Using the usual rules, we find that the general solution is$$(A+Bx)e^{3x}$$

What is it it about $(A+Bx)e^{3x}$ that makes it the general solution whereas $Ae^{3x}$ is not?

Comment: Because $Bx e^{3x}$ solves the ODE, so $Ae^{3x}$ isn't a general solution, because there exist solutions that aren't in that form.

It happens because of the repeated root $3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general solution describes the most general case. The solution

$$Ae^{3x}$$

is a *specific* case of the general solution. It is the specific case where $B=0$. For ODEs, there is a theorem which states that an ODE of order $n$ has $n$ linearly independent solutions. This means that there are $n$ constants (in this case, $n$ is two and the constants are $A$ and $B$) which each multiply a linearly independent solution. If you have an ODE of order $n$ and have less than $n$ constants in your solution, then your solution is not general, it is specific to the case where one (or more) constants are zero.

Comment: Thanks, very clear.

Answer (score 2):

This ordinary constant coefficient linear differential equation is 2nd order. The general solution (from which all other solutions are obtained by suitable combinations) contains $2$ independent solutions.

The auxiliary equation, having a repeated root, only generates one of those two solutions. A second, independent, solution is generated by multiplying the solution you already have by $x$. This extra $x$ ensures it's independent of the first solution. The general solution is then all linear combinations of the 2 independent solutions
$$
Ae^{3x}+Bxe^{3x}
$$

Comment: Thanks for that.

Answer (score 2):

You should integrate the Differential equation to see why the solution you have is the general solution
$$y''-6y'+9y = 0$$
$$(y'-3y)'-3(y'-3y)=0$$
Substitute $z=y'-3y$
$$z'-3z=0$$
$$(ze^{-3x})'=0$$
Integrate :
$$ze^{-3x}=A$$
$$y'-3y=Ae^{3x}$$
$$(ye^{-3x})'=A$$
Integrate again :
$$ye^{-3x}=Ax+B$$
Finally 
$$y(x)=e^{3x}(Ax+B)$$
And that's the general solution of the differential equation. And you have two constants $(A,B)$ since the DE is of order two.

Answer (score 0):

*Another approach*

Considering
$$y''-6y'+9y = 0$$ let
$$y=z \,e^{3x}\implies e^{3x}\,z''=0 \implies z''=0\implies z=a+b x\implies y=e^{3x}(a+bx)$$